# Problem with "task" package -- too many "row"s?

Tags: tasks

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasks[
counter-format={tsk[a])}, %%a,A,r,R
label-format=\bfseries,
label-width=1.5em,
label-align=left,        %% or right as you wish
label-offset=0.5em,
item-indent=2em,
after-item-skip=0pt,
after-skip=-0.5\baselineskip,,
before-skip=-0.5\baselineskip,,
resume=false             %% comment this for not to resume
]{problems}[\item](3)    %% (4) here makes all of them in 4 columns



\begin{document}

\begin{problems}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{problems}


\end{document}
```

Everything works fine with fewer `\item`s. Does that mean it does not support when there are too many rows? or continues to a second page?

I got the warning:

```
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorted!

I was using letters and there are only 26 letters.

So solution is to use `counter-format={tsk[1])}`.

On my god, the warning message is misleading!

Comment: If you look at the complete log you find `! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.`. And if you look at the PDF produced by the example in your question it is also quite obvious :) You can also load package `alphalph` and tell `tasks` to use it: `\NewPatternFormat{aa}{\alphalph}` and then `counter-format={tsk[aa])}`

Comment: By the way: `! Undefined control sequence.` is not a warning message but an error message (LaTeX distinguishes between those)

Comment: @clemens I did not ask latex to compile it once I saw the message. In general, I tend to "solve" the problem before I force it to compile. I would say there was nothing that was `Undefined`. All was defined perfectly. That to me was just confusing. Thanks about the other suggestion.