# \tasks \alphalph

Tags: tasks

I need to give a huge list of matrices to diagonalise. I read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282015/problem-with-task-package-too-many-rows), but I can't figure how to make it work.

Here is my code, in fact, I have many more matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tasks} 
\usepackage{etex, 
amsmath,
amsthm,
amsfonts, 
amssymb,     
latexsym, 
mathtools,
etoolbox,
thmtools,
float}
\NewPatternFormat{aa}{\alphalph}
\settasks{counter-format = {tsk[aa]}, label-offset = 5mm}
\begin{document}
Which one of the entries does not fit with the others?
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r]4 & 3\\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix*}$   
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r]2 & 4\\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix*}$   
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 4 & 1\\ 4 & 4\end{bmatrix*}$
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r]2 & 1\\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix*}$   
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Macro `\alphalph` is provided by package `alphalph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{
  etex,
  alphalph, % ADDED
  amsmath,
  amsthm,
  amsfonts,
  amssymb,
  latexsym,
  mathtools,
  etoolbox,
  thmtools,
  float,
}
\NewPatternFormat{aa}{\alphalph}
\settasks{counter-format = {tsk[aa]}, label-offset = 5mm}
\begin{document}
Which one of the entries does not fit with the others?
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r]4 & 3\\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix*}$
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r]2 & 4\\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix*}$
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 4 & 1\\ 4 & 4\end{bmatrix*}$
  \task     $\begin{bmatrix*}[r]2 & 1\\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix*}$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]